# Salvar Data na Tabela UTC Brasil

Tags: mysql, laravel

Estou fazendo uma inserção em uma tabela do MySql que contém vários campos de data.

Deixei no **default** da coluna *created_at* da tabela o valor *current_timestamp*.

Se eu faço um **INSERT** agora, ele está inserindo: 12:29:00. Ou seja, três horas a mais.

E se eu faço o **INSERT** nessa coluna manualmente pelo Laravel, assim:

`$model->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Ele também insere com três horas a mais.

Como eu faço para corrigir isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ir a `config/app`, e alterar a `timezone`:

```
'timezone' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',
```

Creio que isto já resolve o seu problema, deixo [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php) a lista de timezones Americanas, acho que deve ser alguma destas que quer

Comment: Boa. Nem lembrava dessa parada.

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira de resolver isso de forma global é definir o timezone adequado(America_Sao_Paulo) no php.ini.

Procure ou crie essa linha no php.ini e reinicie o apache após a alteração.

```
date.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo
```